# VueJS 2: passing a lot of property values to a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the best way to pass a lot of property values to a component?

Right now I am doing this:

```
<list-li 
  v-for="item in items" 
  :key="item.id" 
  :id="item.id" 
  :user="item.user" 
  :branch="item.branch" 
  :title="item.title"
></list-li>
```

Is there a way to pass one variable containing all the data instead of having to write out `:someValue` of every data value?

Also, if `item.title` does not exist, what would happen with `:title="item.title"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an object to the `v-bind` directive. Each property of the object will assign that property name and value to the component.

So in your case, you could just pass the `item`:

```
<list-li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" v-bind="item"></list-li>
```

Comment: How do I then use the data inside my component eg ``{{ title }}`` ?

Comment: Inside the `list-li` component? Just like that: `{{ title }}`

Comment: Ah sorry, in my component I wrote ``props: ['item.title']`` had to change it to to just **title**